# When does window becomes initialized in NSWindowController

Tags: macos, nswindowcontroller

I'm examining Apple's tutorial OSXGLEssentials. There is a class named GLEssentialsWindowController that inherits NSWindowController. It has method

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
```

but argument `window` is `nil`.

I have added method

```
 -(void)windowDidLoad
```

but it is just not called.

However, at some magic moment field `window` becomes initialized, because when I press "F" button the app switches from windowed mode to fullscreen and I can see that `self.window` is not null at this moment.

So my question is: when does `window` field becomes initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether it's connected in the xib?

One option is to set the window controller as the windows owner using the *File Owner* proxy. At runtime the outlet will the be connected auto-magically.

And you can always set a watchpoint in Xcode to detect when somebody changes the value of your variable.

Comment: I think this is probably correct. If the window outlet weren't connected in the NIB, that would explain the symptoms. The code for switching into full-screen when "F" is pressed, directly calls `-setWindow:`, which would explain how the `window` property becomes non-`nil` without `-windowDidLoad` being called. I suspect the example would get confused once you switch out of full-screen mode, because it then calls `-setWindow:` with the old value of the `window` property, which was `nil`.